# loop through column "U" containing date to find all instances of 30 days past and set value of row to "null"

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that appends data into a specified row.

```
function appendRowsV(sheet, data, optColumn) {
 if (!Array.isArray(data)) {
    data = [[data]];
  } else if (!Array.isArray(data[0])) {
    data = [data];
  }
  const rowStart = getNextArchiveV(sheet, optColumn);
  const columnStart = Number(optColumn) || 1;
  const numRows = data.length;
  const numColumns = data[0].length;
  const range = sheet.getRange(rowStart, columnStart, numRows, numColumns);
  range.setValues(data);
  var aDate = new Date();
  range.offset(0, 20, 1, 1).setValue(aDate).setNumberFormat("m/d/yy");
  return { range: range, rowStart: rowStart, columnStart: columnStart, numRows: numRows,  numColumns: numColumns };
```

I place the current date in column "U" of that row. In another function I need to loop through column "U" and find all instances where date is 30 days in the past. When a match is found set values of that row to null.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
function hideRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Archived Videos'); 
  var dateRange = sh.getRange(3, 20, 1, 1); 
  var dates = dateRange.getDisplayValues();
  var currentDate = new Date(); 

  for(var i = 20; i < dates.length; i++){
    var date = new Date(dates[i][0].replace(/-/g, '\/').replace(/T.+/, ''));
    if(date.valueOf() <= currentDate.valueOf()){  
      sh.getformulas(i+2);
      sh.setformulas();
    }
  }
  
}
```

Can somebody please look at what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Row with dates older than 30 days

```
function rowWithDateOlderThan30days() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheetname");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const dtv = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate() - 30).valueOf();
  let rows = [];
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(new Date(r[20]).valueOf() < dtv) {
      rows.push(i+1);
    }
  })
  Logger.log(rows.join(','));
}
```

Comment: I changed the name the sheet and the log shows nothing. Any clues why?

Comment: I just tried it and it works for me.  Column U is column 21

Comment: What is the format of you dates? Maybe you dates are not in a form that the Date() constructor recognizes

Comment: Nevermind it works. but I need to set the row value to null.

Comment: I see it logs the match but how can I set that rows value?

Comment: try using fill method

Comment: Thats not what I mean. I need to get values of that row so I can set values of row.

Comment: In my code r is the row

Comment: I have been able to do Logger.log(r); and get the information in that row. I would like to do something like var newvalue = r.getvalues(); nv.setvalues(null); however this does not work. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: r is an array not a range.

Comment: Understood. I need to convert this so I can change the values. I'm unclear as to how to do this.

Comment: `sh.getRange(i + 1,  index + 1).getA1Notation()`  indexes go from 0 to r.length - 1 and column go from 1 to r.length

Comment: I am so sorry but I'm not getting it. In essence I am looking to clear the row returned by setting the rows value to null keeping any data validation intact. From all of your code I am so lost.

Comment: How can you be so lost there's only ten lines of code and it's really simply stuff. This is how you convert a row to a range `sh.getRange(i + 1,  index + 1).getA1Notation() `

Comment: it says index is undefined.

Comment: Think about it.

Comment: if I replace index with r it throws an error. I am still trying to learn scripting but this is not computing.

Comment: You have to pick the index of the element of r that you wish to access and then add one to it to get the column.

Comment: index of r. I'm confused.

Comment: Can you edit your initial code to reflect what you are talking about?

Comment: I'd prefer that you attempt to figure it out on your own first

Comment: What parameter of getRange is index + 1 in `sh.getRange(i + 1,  index + 1).getA1Notation()`

Comment: column is 20. is that what you mean.

Comment: So if column is 20 then what is the index of r for the same column

Comment: sh.getRange(i + 1,  20 + 1).getA1Notation(); I think.

Comment: The column we are talking about is actually 21 so you are correct.  So I assume that you  can now complete the code on your own.